# Closing form in secondary screen

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multiple-monitors

I have a application that opens two forms in the primary and secondary monitors. Both Forms have the same code and I have them setup so that when I hit the Escape key both forms should close, but one forms does not close.

Code: Form1

```
Public class Form1
Dim obj As New Form2
Dim obj2 As New Form3

Public Closecheck As Boolean = False

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
                Me.Hide()

                Obj2.Location = Screen.AllScreens(UBound(Screen.AllScreens)).Bounds.Location
                Obj.Show()
                Obj2.Show()
End Sub
```

Form2

```
Public Class Form2

Prive Sub Form2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
            Form1.Closecheck = True
            Form3.Closeout3()
            Me.Close()
Form1.show
End if
    Public Sub Closeout2()
            If Form1.Closecheck = True Then
                MsgBox(Form1.Closecheck)
                Me.Close()
            End If
        End Sub
```

Form3

```
Public Class Form3

 Private Sub Form3_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
            Form1.Closecheck = True
            Form2.Closeout2()
            Me.Close()
Form1.show

End Sub
Public Sub Closeout3()
        If Form1.Closecheck = True Then
            MsgBox(Form1.Closecheck)
            Me.Close()
        End If

    End Sub
```

The `MsgBox` on Form2 and Form3 are just there to let me know that they are finding the Booloean `Closecheck` But when the second `MsgBox` opens in its screen the entire screen is frozen and I can not close the `MsgBox`. Due most likely by the fact the Form is still open.

Comment: You are using the default instance of your forms when you do Form1.CloseCheck and the like. Your forms are called obj and obj2. Form2 and Form3 are not visible. You need to set the Parent in Form1 when you create them

Comment: Also a typo on line 2: you want `Form2` not `From2`

Comment: Using MsgBox for debugging is not ideal.  The message window can interfere with your code operations.  It's better to use Debug.WriteLine, etc.

Comment: @MarkHall So I should be looking at something on Form1 like `Obj.Owner = Me`  Never set a Parent before.

Comment: Yes, you can do that or you can set the Owner in your obj.Show by doing obj.Show(Me). You would then subscribe to your obj and obj2 FormClosing events so that Form1 can close the other Form

Comment: @MarkHall Are you talking about `AddHandler` when you are talking about subscribing to `FormClosing` Event?

Comment: Yes I am. Sorry I can't give you more details.  I am flying today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using the variables declared in Form1.  Form2 and Form3 simply close themselves and let Form1 take care of the rest.  Note how `F2` and `F3` have been declared as `WithEvents`.

Form1:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Resources

Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents F2 As Form2
    Private WithEvents F3 As Form3

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If IsNothing(F2) Then
            F2 = New Form2
            F2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
            F2.Location = Screen.AllScreens.First.Bounds.Location
        End If
        If IsNothing(F3) Then
            F3 = New Form3
            F3.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
            F3.Location = Screen.AllScreens.Last.Bounds.Location
        End If

        F2.Show()
        F3.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub F2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles F2.FormClosed
        F2 = Nothing
        If Not IsNothing(F3) Then
            F3.Close()
        Else
            Me.Show()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub F3_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles F3.FormClosed
        F3 = Nothing
        If Not IsNothing(F2) Then
            F2.Close()
        Else
            Me.Show()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Form2:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Form3:

```
Public Class Form3

    Private Sub Form2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```